# Sort TFS Work Item query by user

Tags: tfs

I would like to create a TFS query that shows what each user did during a Sprint. Is it possible to sort the query by the `Assigned To` field.

> [image: TFS Query Editor]

I realise that I can create a `Flat list of work items` query, then click on the column name to order it, but I would prefer to have the query use the sort order by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Column Options at the top of the query editor and then click on the Sort Columns tab.  You can then select the AssignedTo field (followed by a date field or ID perhaps)

[image: Column Options]